# Mongo-express connection error: Load balancer mode requires driver version 4+ : Mongo-express:latest docker image

Tags: mongo-express

```
could not connect to database using connectionString: "mongodb-url"
(node:6) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Load balancer mode requires driver version 4+
at QueryReqWrap.callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:111:27)
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:205:10)
(node:6) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm trying to connect mongo-express in docker container to my mongo-db

Comment: please edit your post providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). also I suggest to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)